# Single windows preview/thumbnail for two dialog objects from same class

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have built a C++/MFC program where - next to the main GUI dialog - two dialogs are used to display a PNG image divided over two monitors.

The two dialogs are created from the same class. The problem is that they are rendered as one windows preview/thumbnail, next to the main GUI thumbnail. Thus, I can only see and select one of the dialogs from the windows taskbar.

I would like to have each dialog be represented by it's own windows preview. Is this possible when both dialogs are objects from the same class?

Comment: I believe you can do this by calling [`ITaskbarList3::RegisterTab()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391694(v=vs.85).aspx) for each of the child dialogs. [Background reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#thumbnails).